# Problem with execution of CLI command in IndexController.php

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have the following code:

```
class IndexController extends pm_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

            shell_exec('php /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/hello-world/script.php');

            $file = file_get_contents( "/usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/hello-world/tune" );
            var_dump($file);
            var_dump(file_exists($file));



            $this->view->message =  $file ;
    }
}
```

In /views/scripts/index/index.phtml

`<?php echo  $this->message; ?>`

So it basically prints the content of "tune" file on a page, but I want it to execute the shell command (another php script actually) via shell_exec().

The problem is that shell_exec() does not work - script.php doesn't run.

I understand that I'm missing something very important here but can't figure out what.

p.s. sorry for such question - I'm new to php

Comment: How do you know if it gets executed or not? What does it return? What is it suppose to do?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson script.php rewrites /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/hello-world/tune file a bit, but there are no changes in the file after the page is open

Comment: What does your `shell_exec()` call return?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson nothing - it should only run the script. I also tried to approach this in another way - by adding the following line to indexAction():

exec("/usr/bin/perl /root/MySQLTuner-perl/mysqltuner.pl $username $password",$output);

this should return an array, but $output is alway empty. Same code works fine in a separate php script

Comment: Example of the code where exec() works:

<?php
  
$username = 'root';
$password = 'xxxx';

exec("/usr/bin/perl /root/MySQLTuner-perl/mysqltuner.pl $username $password",$output);
$fp = fopen('tune', 'w');
fwrite($fp, print_r($output, TRUE));
fclose($fp);

?>    An array is written into a file